# Windows server 2008 r2 Task Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows

I have created Windows Task Scheduler. The task is running fine but I don't get any notification.I did VB scripting and added that file to the task.ON my local machine I am getting an email but when I am running on production I won't.
everything I am doing same. the only difference is a server and local machine.

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Call ScheduleTask() 

Sub ScheduleTask()
On Error Resume Next

Dim objRequest
Dim URL

Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
URL = "http://localhost:59409/ScheduledJobs/Documents"

objRequest.open "GET", URL , false

objRequest.Send

Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Is the SMTP port open in prod?  Can you confirm that you can send email from any app in prod?

Comment: Yes. I am getting an email when a file is uploaded. Only not getting when it is past due.